# jQuery dynmically create arrays from multiple select

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select and a button that generate's another multiple select on click. What i want is to get all values from each multiple select, but not all in one array. I want an array for each multiple select (which will be added dynamic into `DOM`) containing values from that multiple select. 
I can generate selects from which I select values, but cannot make a multidimensional array with arrays of values.

Here's my code:

```
    $('#generate_variations').click( function () {
        var variations = [];
        $('.vars').each(function () {
            var v = [];
            $(this.selected).each(function(i, selected){
                v.push($("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(", "));
            });
            variations.push(v);
        }); 
    });
```

`.vars` is the class of each select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on selected `options` like

```
$('#generate_variations').click( function () {
    var variations = $('.vars').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(", "); 
});
```

However if you have set `select-multiple`, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns an array containing  the value of each selected option. In this scenario you can use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Merging_two_arrays) to merge

```
$('#generate_variations').click( function () {
    var variations = [];
    $('.vars').each(function () {
         Array.prototype.push.apply(variations, $(this).val());
    }); 
});
```